# Create a running counter based on ID and date

Tags: sas

I have 3 variables and a counter has to be created based on them.

Input:

```
ID  window start  window end 
1   29oct20         12mar21
1   31oct20         08Feb21
1   31oct21         08feb21
1   31oct21         08feb21
2   06Nov20         11Apr21
2   06Nov20         11Apr21
2   27Nov20         01Apr19
```

Expected output:

```
ID  window start  window end  priority_count
1   29oct20         12mar21      1
1   31oct20         08Feb21      2
1   31oct21         08feb21      2
1   31oct21         08feb21      2
2   06Nov20         11Apr21      1
2   06Nov20         11Apr21      1
2   27Nov20         01Apr19      2
```

So for every `ID` a new count should start once a new date comes.

I have been using this code

```
data want;
set have;
by ID window_start window_end;
if first.ID and first.window_start and first.window_endthen priority_count=1;
else priority_count+1;
run;
```

But it gives:

```
priority_count
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
```

Comment: Do you have typos in your start dates? How can start be after end?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if those are typos but there are several observations for which `window_start` is after `window_end`.

Using the [LAG](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/vdmmlcdc/8.1/lefunctionsref/n0l66p5oqex1f2n1quuopdvtcjqb.htm) function

```
data want;
    set have;
    by id;
    _lag=lag(window_start);

    if first.id then priority_count=1;
    else do;
        if window_start ne _lag then
            priority_count + 1;
    end;
    drop _lag;
run;

 ID window_start window_end priority_count
 1  29OCT2020    12MAR2021        1
 1  31OCT2020    08FEB2021        2
 1  31OCT2020    08FEB2021        2
 1  31OCT2020    08FEB2021        2
 2  06NOV2020    11APR2021        1
 2  06NOV2020    11APR2021        1
 2  27NOV2020    01APR2019        2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track but need a slight modifications on your IF statements to reflect the logic.

- Set to 0 at first of each ID
- Increment if the window_end changes (or window_start since they're consistent in your example). Setting it to 0 initially means you can increment without worrying if it's the first or not.

```
data want;
set have;
by ID window_start window_end;
if first.ID then priority_count=0;

if first.window_end then priority_count+1;

run;
```